# How can I show with PhantomJS the url of the processed page in the generated PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, phantomjs

My goal was to generate a PDF from every page included in the sitemap of a website created with Rails. I'm using PhantomJS to get it. I'm quite new in this field, but I could do it, but when I was finished, I realized that it would be usable also to see at the beginning of every PDF the url of the page from which the PDF was generated, so I can browse quicker to the page (the site has over hundred pages).

Here is the Javascript:

```
// Render Sitemap to file

var RenderUrlsToFile, arrayOfUrls, system;

system = require("system");

/*
Render given urls
@param array of URLs to render
@param callbackPerUrl Function called after finishing each URL, including the last URL
@param callbackFinal Function called after finishing everything
*/

var getFileNumber = function(urlIndex) {
  if (urlIndex <10) {
    return "00" + urlIndex;
  } else {
    if (urlIndex <100) {
      return "0" + urlIndex;
    } else {
      return urlIndex;
    }
  }
};

RenderUrlsToFile = function(urls, callbackPerUrl, callbackFinal) {
    var getFilename, next, page, retrieve, urlIndex, webpage;
    urlIndex = 0;
    webpage = require("webpage");
    page = null;
    getFilename = function() {
    return "rendermulti-" + getFileNumber(urlIndex) + ".pdf";
    };
    next = function(status, url, file) {
        page.close();
        callbackPerUrl(status, url, file);
        return retrieve();
    };
    retrieve = function() {
        var url;
        if (urls.length > 0) {
            url = urls.shift();
            urlIndex++;
            page = webpage.create();
            page.viewportSize = {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1880
            };
            page.settings.userAgent = "Phantom.js bot";
            return page.open(url, function(status) {
                var file;
                file = getFilename();
                if (status === "success") {
                    return window.setTimeout((function() {

                      // !!!!!!!!!!!!! Doesn't work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                      page.evaluate(function() {
                        var x = document.getElementById("logoAndNavigation");
                        var newP = document.createElement("P")
                        var textnode = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
                        newP.appendChild(textnode)
                        x.insertBefore(newP, x.childNodes[0]);
                      });
                      // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                      page.render("tempPdfs/" + file);
                      return next(status, url, file);
                    }), 200);
                } else {
                    return next(status, url, file);
                }
            });
        } else {
            return callbackFinal();
        }
    };
    return retrieve();
};

// This makes an array with all the urls inside the sitemap
var arrayOfUrls = [''];
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml', function() {
  var content = page.content;
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content,'text/xml');
  var loc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('loc');
  for(var i=0; i < loc.length; i++)
  {
    var url=loc[i].textContent;
    arrayOfUrls.push(url);
  }
});




RenderUrlsToFile(arrayOfUrls, (function(status, url, file) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        return console.log("Unable to render '" + url + "'");
    } else {
        return console.log("Rendered '" + url + "' at '" + file + "'");
    }
}), function() {
    return phantom.exit();
});
```

I tried to solve the issue with the urls, with the code framed with the comment

```
// !!!!!!!!!!!!! Doesn't work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I wanted to show the url inside an element of the page, that has the id #logoAndNavigation, but I get this error:

NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

If I use only a string like "hello" inside the variable textnode, it works, but not if I try to use the url of the page.

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appendChild` expects a node not a string. You probably mean to use

```
var x = document.getElementById("logoAndNavigation");
var newP = document.createElement("p"); // small p
var textnode = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
newP.innerHTML = textnode; // this
x.insertBefore(newP, x.childNodes[0]);
```

You can also use the example of [**printheaderfooter.js**](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/printheaderfooter.js) to add the URL directly to the header or footer.